# Problem with \newcommand{\nal}{\end{align*}}

Tags: macros, align

Why do these newcommands result in error when used?

```
\newcommand{\bal}{\begin{align*}}
\newcommand{\nal}{\end{align*}}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you please provide a complete compilable example, which we can copy and test? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some code which does exactly what you want. As you can read in the answers of the dupe question, this is not really good advice. There is very little gain in obfuscating your code like this. You just safe very few key-strokes which are not even needed when using a good TeX editor. Btw., like this you would have to define new macros for the other align environment... so why invent the wheel a second time?

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\def\bal#1\nal{\begin{align*}#1\end{align*}}

\begin{document}
 \bal
 a&=c\\
 b&=d
 \nal
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like the way you think.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Thanks, but this is not new. Can't take that credits ;-)

Comment: Sorry, but this is bad advice. I can't see how `\bal...\nal` is clearer than `\begin{align*}...\end{align*}`. I know this solves the OP's question, but a note about this being a bad approach should appear.